# What is a self biasing of a transistor. Explain with a circuit of it

Tags: transistors, biasing

There was a question in my semester exam. "Define stability factor. Explain self-bias circuit with diagram and derive expression for stability factor."

Now after searching a bit I found that when the collector voltage is not directly provided by a dc supply source, the biasing is called self-bias. Then both voltage divider bias and collector feedback bias are self bias.

Could you explain the answer to this question in your own way.

Comment: You can easily research this my way https://www.google.com/search?q=Define+stability+factor.+Explain+self-bias+circui&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b The rate of change collector current Ic with respect to the collector leakage
current Icbo is called stability factor, denoted by S.

Comment: So what did your prof provide in your class notes? As it must have been covered, just so we have an idea...

Answer (score 4):

The stability factor (S) for a fixed bias circuit is (1+β). β is equal to Beta, hFE, or the DC gain of the transistor. Self bias was important back in the days when stages were connected by capacitors.

It was nothing more than feeding some collector voltage back to the base. The gain is controlled by the ratio of R1/R3, so even if this transistor had a gain of 100, R1/R3 limits the gain as a circuit to 10.

R2/R4 form a 5:1 divider but the transistors feedback loop means at least 0.65 volts on the base, but with Q1 having a Beta of 100 the voltage at the emitter is more like 0.65 volts, for a CE current of 650 uA. The base then would have about 1.3 volts on it, not including any injected waveform.

As it is you should have about 6.5 volts at the collector, about 1/2 the supply voltage. This depend greatly on the transistors Beta. An ancient transistor with a gain of 10 would need much lower resistor values for proper bias.

Study the feedback loop and you can see where it is self-stabilizing, even with some temperature change. If the collector voltage drops, so does the base current, which stops the collector from dropping. You must choose resistors based on the transistors Beta and the input loading of the previous stage.

C1 and R4 form a time constant, a high pass filter, so their values affect mostly the bandwidth of the signal at the low end. In this case it is -3dB at about 0.153 HZ. This would not affect audio, just block DC from a previous stage.

R4 could be omitted if R2 had a high enough value to match the gain of Q1. It may have to be 500 K or so, as long as the CE current is 50 uA to 1.5 mA. Any higher current and schott noise and self-heating begins to be an issue if more stages are after this one. Too low of a current and you lack drive power for the next stage, and all transistors have a collector cut-off current.

Thanks to @LvW reminder that the emitter resistor, and 1 K is a substantial value, helps out by combining with Q1 and its fixed base voltage to act as a constant-current sink. This also helps cancel out CE current drift with temperature. Theses combined feed backs give the circuit a good 'stability factor'.

Low noise pre-amp stages maybe biased for a CE current of 50 uA to 100 uA, to keep schott noise to a minimum.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6bgT9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

The circuit as shown by SPARKY256 in his contribution contains TWO feedback elements. And BOTH contribute to the self-biasing feature. As mentioned by SPARKY256, the first is the feedback path consisting of R2 and R4.

However, even when R2 would be connected to the 12 volt supply (that means: no feedback effect from the collector side) the emitter resistor R3 provides negative current-controlled voltage feedback.

Explanation: The bipolar transistor acts as a voltage-controlled current source - that means: Ic is controlled by Vbe. Hence, an unwanted increase in Ic (resp. Ie) - perhaps caused by temperature effects - creates an increase od the voltage drop across Re and, thus, reduces Vbe and Ic correspondingly.

Comment (edit): Stability factor

Using a term like "stability factor" it is helpful to add a definition. This is necessary because there are more than one single stability factors. These factors tell us how much the wanted collecor current depends on system uncertainties (changes) of temperature or saturation current Ico or parts tolerances or supply voltages...

Answer (score 1):

This self-bias circuit is excellent way to bias a photo-transistor for good sensitivity, while removing SOLAR and 60Hz interference.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHWNsB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>